# Using social-icons in angular material 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-material2

I am moving an `angular 4` application from `bootstrap` to `material-2`. The previous version was using [bootstrap-social](https://github.com/lipis/bootstrap-social) which is based on bootstrap and `font-awesome`. It allowed for the following to be rendered:

[image: social icons]

What would be the [angular-material2](https://github.com/angular/material2) 'way' of rendering social sign-in icons? 
One would not mix font-awesome and bootstrap with material?

Answer (score 2):

In Material 2, you can provide your own icons in addition to the icons provided by Material Design Icons.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MdIconRegistry } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'icon-usage',
  templateUrl: 'icon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['icon.component.css']
})
export class IconComponent {
  constructor(iconRegistry: MdIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('angular', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('/assets/angular-icon.svg'));
  }
}
```

See it here: [Angular Material 2 - Icons](http://material-platform.azurewebsites.net/icon)

Also see: [Angular Material 2 - Typography](http://material-platform.azurewebsites.net/typography)